# Python: FastAPI and Beanie - Scoped Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, odm, scoped

In ASP.NET Core you have the concept of adding a service/object as "scoped" which means that it is the same object within a request. We used this concept e.g. to get the user out of the Bearer token header and provide the user data project-wide over a "CurrentUserService".

I'm searching for a way to do this using Pythons FastAPI and Beanie framework. Here is the use-case:
I want to use the event-based actions of beanie to automatically set the user data before a database update. Here is the current state of the code:

```
class DataEntity(Document):
    name: str
    last_modified_by: str

    @before_event(Replace)
    def set_version_data(self):
        #here the current user should be set into last_modified_by
```

So my question is: How can I set the last_modified_by field on this event level?

I already tried to use the FastAPI dependencies, because they look like a scoped wrap-around I searched for:

```
async def get_current_user(x_user: str = Header(None)) -> str:
    return x_user


class DataEntity(Document):
    name: str
    last_modified_by: str

    @before_event(Replace)
    def set_version_data(self, current_user: str = Depends(get_current_user)):
        self.last_modified_by = current_user
```

But this is not handled right and I get the error "pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for DataEntity: last_modified_by - str type expected (type=type_error.str)".

Comment: Generally dependencies are only resolved from the controller and any dependencies present in the hierarchy from those dependencies - which means that your `current_user: str = Depends(get_current_user)` ends up with just a reference to a `Depends` object that won't get resolved (since the event will be handled outside of the request context). I'm not sure what a good way to solve it using the event handling would be, so my solution would probably be to assign the `last_modified_by` part in a data entity service instead of as an event.

Comment: The data entity service would be created through a `Depends(get_data_entity_service)`, in which that function in turn would have a dependency on the current user, which would be given to the data entity service constructor. The methods in the data entity service could then use this current user information to set a value for the field when saving or updating the object.

Comment: I already suspected that `Depends(...)` would no longer be evaluated at this level. 

I also wanted to implement a service first, but since I'm not that deep into Python yet, I don't know how to implement a service that saves and returns the current user in the "request scope" as I know it from .NET.

Do you have any idea how to do that?